# Are static constructors guaranteed to not be inlined?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I guess so!

EDIT: The motivation for this question is: It seems to me that due to the semantics of static constructors they could never be safely inlined.

Comment: You need to read Beforefieldinit concept on type ctors by jon skeet.

Comment: I don't believe that would help.

Comment: Where would they be inlined and what would (could) it matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jitter's inlining strategy is an implementation detail -- subject to change at any time -- so there are pretty much no guarantees about what can or can't be inlined.

Having said that, it's difficult to see how a static constructor could ever be safely inlined, bearing in mind the guarantees provided by the C# and CLI specs regarding static constructors and type initialisation.

From the [Microsoft C# specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) (section 10.12):

> The static constructor for a closed class type executes at most once
>   in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor
>   is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an
>   application domain:
>
> - An instance of the class type is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.

And from the [ECMA CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) (section 8.9.5):

> [A class can] optionally specify a method (called `.cctor`) to be
>   called to initialize the type.
>
> The semantics of when and what triggers execution of such type
>   initialization methods, is as follows:
>
> - A type can have a type-initializer method, or not.
>
> A type can be specified as having a relaxed semantic for its
>   type-initializer method (for convenience below, we call this relaxed
>   semantic **BeforeFieldInit**).
>
> If marked **BeforeFieldInit** then the type's initializer method is
>   executed at, or sometime before, first access to any static field
>   defined for that type.
>
> If not marked **BeforeFieldInit** then that type's initializer method
>   is executed at (i.e., is triggered by):
>
> - first access to any static field of that type, or
> - first invocation of any static method of that type, or
> - first invocation of any instance or virtual method of that type if
>     it is a value type or
> - first invocation of any constructor for that type.

(Note that C# classes with a static constructor *will not* have `beforefieldinit` semantics. C# classes without a static constructor will have `beforefieldinit` semantics.)

Comment: Please could you back this up with evidence? Your second thought is the motivation for the question.

Comment: Note I'm NOT asking about the inlining strategy, but about the constraints placed upon it by the CLI spec.

Comment: @Pete: I've added quotes from the relevant sections of the spec documents. I'm not sure if these will provide the guarantees that you're looking for though, since the jitter has free reign to do whatever it likes within the constraints of the specs. (If the CLR team discovered a way to massively boost performance by inlining static constructors without breaking spec then they might decide to do that. Maybe they already have done it!)

Comment: Thanks Luke! I know about *these* semantics - they are the motivation for the question. I'm looking for someone to tell me whether there is (or, probably, is not) an explicit guarantee about inlining. Cheers! Pete.

Comment: @Pete: I can tell you there is no *explicit* guarantee, because there are *no* guarantees regarding the implementation details of the jitter's behaviour (except, of course, that it shouldn't break the semantics of the program and the guarantees provided by the C# and CLI specifications).

Comment: In my opinion, it's unlikely that static constructors could be safely inlined, except perhaps in a few corner cases. And anyway, the benefits of inlining code that is guaranteed to only run either once or not at all are likely to be pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

The only guarantees you have are the following :

- A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.
- The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program.

Comment: These are not the *only* guarantees provided by the CLI.